# I have installed PHP 5.6 but still error is shown for laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have installed latest xampp which contains PHP 5.6 version. Despite of this the following error is shown when I try to install laravel.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: can you add your `composer.json` file content here

Comment: also check `mcrypt` extension. You need to add that to your PHP, http://laravel.io/forum/05-30-2014-mcrypt-php-extension-required?page=1

Comment: mcrypt is needed for older versions of Laravel only. Check http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation for 5.1 requirements, or change 5.1 to whatever version you are trying to install.

Comment: The problem is with the packages listed in your `composer.json` file - composer is not able to reconcile all the different version numbers. The error message should also list which packages it's having trouble with. Post that info (plus your `composer.json`, as @GaneshGhalame suggested) and maybe someone here can help.

Answer (score -2):

Here you'll find a phpinfo() sample on my Mac OS X 10.10.5 dev platform

Hope it'll help!

[phpinfo output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tg30iw7fr8b0zts/phpinfo_laravel_sample.html?dl=0)

Comment: When I run phpinfo() function in browser it shows PHP version 5.6 but in terminal PHP version 5.3 is shown